# How to give an empty td a class?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am displaying a table. Some cells of this table are filled with content. But there are some cells that are empty. What i want is that all empty cells have a different background color. How can i do that?
How can i check if a td is empty?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use js/jquery to check if a cell is empty or not. Based on that you can add a class and give a `background-color` to the same.

Or if you want a css only approach, you can use `:empty` selector. But the problem with `:empty` is that it will not consider a td an empty one if there is just a few space in it. Check the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("table td").each(function (index, eachCell) {
    if ($(eachCell).html().trim().length === 0) {
      $(eachCell).addClass("empty-cell");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.empty-cell {
  background-color: red;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
}


td:empty {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td></td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>      </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty) selector:

**Demo:**

```js
//You can loop and remove the space charcater from cells
document.querySelectorAll('table tr > td').forEach(c => c.textContent = c.textContent.trim());
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
table tr > td:empty {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>February</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>March</td>
    <td>$90</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>&nbsp; </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Problem with this approach is, if there is a couple of space/s in the cell, the cell won't be consider as empty.

Comment: @AbinThaha, why should empty cells have space in them?

Comment: Suppose if the data is coming from a database, which was stored on the first time from an FE submit form and it can happen that the data was saved with an extra spaces only.

Comment: @AbinThaha, probably you could ask OP to add this in the question, then I will think of updating the answer based on the update.

Comment: Probably. He is the one we need :)

Comment: @AbinThaha you are right.. I tried it with :empty but it wont work because there is a space (&nbsp) in it... but why? wat can i do so that the cell is considered as "full empty"?

Comment: Check my answer. You need to use js/jquery

Comment: @ProdesignWebprojekte, if you have space in some of the cells then you can remove the sapces with `document.querySelectorAll('table tr > td').forEach(c => c.textContent = c.textContent.trim());` updated the answer, please check.